# Moving shapes from one scene/window to another using Python tkinter canvas

Tags: python, tkinter

Here is a rough example of what I want to do(my code is too long and messy to share here): -

```
import tkinter as tk
app = tk.Tk()
w, h = 600, 600

canvas = tk.Canvas(app, width = w, height = h)
canvas.pack()

Rec1 = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100, fill = 'blue', tag = 'move_to_next_window')
Rec2 = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 100, fill='green', tag = 'dont_move_to_next_window')

app.mainloop()
```

I am sorry if I messed up a couple lines but this program should run by creating 2 rectangles. What I need help with is if I initiate a brand new window which is running off different code, how would I move Rec1 and its position to the other window. If its possible, could I copy all of the object's properties in the second window? Thank you for taking the time to read this (the second window can also use the tkinter canvas).

Comment: You can copy a figure options through `itemcget(item, option)` Canvas method probably.

Comment: I doubt that there is a method or function for handy copying figures between different Canvas objects.

Comment: @Splitter , Can i get the shape on the first window from the second window by importing it to the second window or is that not possible?

Comment: as I guessed, there is no such a method. @Bryan has showed how to copy figures to another Canvas object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I need help with is if I initiate a brand new window which is running off different code, how would I move Rec1 and its position to the other window.

You can't move canvas items from one canvas to another. Your only option is to delete the item in the first canvas and add a new item in the other canvas.

> If its possible, could I copy all of the object's properties in the second window?

Yes, you can use the `itemconfigure` method to get all of the properties of a canvas object, you can use `coords` to get the coordinates, and you can get the type with `type` method.

Here's an example function that copies a rectangle from one canvas to another.

```
def copy_canvas_item(source, item_id, destination):
    item_type = source.type(item_id)
    coords = source.coords(item_id)
    # N.B. 'itemconfigure' returns a dictionary where each element
    # has a value that is a list. The currently configured value 
    # is at index position 4
    attrs = {x[0]: x[4] for x in source.itemconfigure(item_id).values()}
    if item_type == "rectangle":
        item_id = destination.create_rectangle(*coords, attrs)
        return item_id
```

Comment: "'itemconfigure' returns a list of values" then can a list have `values` method?

Comment: @Splitter: I can't make sense of that question. I don't see what the result type of `itemconfigure` has to do with methods on a list.

Comment: you wrote "''itemconfigure' returns a list of values" - are you sure that it returns A LIST? Maybe it is a dictionary and not a list? Because you are using `values` method. And no list has `values` method. If `itemconfigure` really returns a list, then how `values` can be used to the list?

Comment: I just checked what is the result type of `itemconfigure` - it is a dictionary. And not a list, as you comment in your code.

Comment: @Splitter: My apologies. I'll update the comment. I was thinking about the the fact that the value was a list. You are right that `itemconfigure()` itself returns a dictionary of lists. I've updated the answer to be more clear.